# Vue-directive: update vs componentUpdated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

The doc states

> update is called after the containing component has updated

and that

> compontedUpdated is called after the containing component and its children have updated.

But what are the actual use cases for choosing one over the other?